# Get project from source and not have to configure build path

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an android project that references a couple of libraries. It is stored in git using a standard .gitignore for android/java.

When another developer gets the project, they seem to have to set the build path for the libraries. Is there a way of setting it up so that they can just get the source, open in eclipse and go rather than messing around?

Comment: these things always depend on naming of the projects in your own IDE and the location on filesystem. if the uploader would have all the dependencies as `jar`s and not as other projects, and have everything in the right place everything should be ok

Comment: Is there any documentation/guidelines on how things should be named and located for this to work?